# SharePoint 2013 - Getting SPSite.Url from SharePoint DB

Tags: database, sharepoint-2013, spweb, spsite, spsitedataquery

I'm working directly against the SharePoint DB (I know it is highly not recommended but I need to, for several reasons).

I'm trying to get the SPSite.Url property ("http://baseurl/sites/somename") but can't figure out how to do that. I can only find and get the second part ("sites/somename") for each site.

Does any one know which stored procedures I need to use in order to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do that is: Retrieving the Farm Id--> Retrieving the Alternate URL Collection Ids--> Retrieving the Alternate URL Collections--> Alternate URL Matching

You can find in this link: [[MS-WSSFO3]: Windows SharePoint Services (WSS): File Operations Database Communications Version 3 Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh624619(v=office.12).aspx) documentation with detailed explanation under this section:

> Site Collection Lookup